# Library or API that gathers user info from social networks

Tags: api, social-networking

I'd like to gather user data in a web-based intranet application similar to [rapportive](http://rapportive.com/), [gist](http://www.gist.com/) and [xobni](http://www.xobni.com/). These services gather and display facebook profiles, twitter streams, linkedin profiles, etc. based on the user's email address in your inbox.

Is there a 3rd party library or API (free or paid) that would provide this kind of data from social networks based on a person's email address? I'd rather not have to go through and create calls for all these different services, not to mention maintaining all these APIs. If there is already a service out there that does the work of search and aggregation that would be so useful.

The application is in C#, so a C# library or wrapper for the API would be nice but definitely not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rapleaf](http://www.rapleaf.com/)... that is the magical service that you can use to find social media data. They have both batch and API REST services.

Comment: now repleaf (towerd@ta) does not provide social network id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Rapleaf appears to be the way to go. But applying for the API key appears to take some time; they may or may not grant an API key. any experience with this?

Comment: After submitting a request, one of their sales people called me later that day to ask about the application I was integrating Rapleaf into. The next day another sales person called me to let me know I was approved and moments later I got the email with the API key. This was back in June 2010, so maybe they have tightened the process since then? They did seem a bit cautious about how it would be used and also the volume of the requests. I would only be making about 40 requests a day and the application was an internal web-based CRM, so it was easily accepted.

Comment: yeah i think so. may i know what is the interview process like when they are asking about your application?

Comment: oh, my API is approved. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a somewhat industrious coder and you only have a select few social networks to search, it isn't so difficult to write simple library functions to access their APIs yourself. They all have different limits on how much searching you are allowed to do, so keep the idea of throttling in mind.

Here's an example of a php function I use to search for people Batchbook by email address, you should be able to modify this to get data from most typical REST APIs:

```
    function getBatchbookContacts($orgname, $apikey, $emailSearch, $page) {
$url = "https://{$orgname}.batchbook.com/api/v1/people.json?auth_token={$apikey}&email={$emailSearch}&page={$page}";
$request = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$request -> setContentType('application/json');
try {
    $response = $request -> send();
    if ($response -> getResponseCode() == '201' || $response -> getResponseCode() == '200') {
        $result_json = $response->getBody();

        return $result_json;
    } else {
        throw new Exception($response -> getBody(), $response -> getResponseCode());
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    throw new Exception('Internal Server Error: ' . $ex -> getMessage(), 500);
}
```

}